# Prometheus Operator change the scrape_interval

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I want to set `scrape_interval` for the Prometheus to 15 seconds. My config below doesn't work, there is an error in the last line. I am wondering how should I config the 15 seconds `scrape_interval`?

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
    kind: Prometheus
    metadata:
      name: main
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: prometheus
      replicas: 1
      version: v1.7.1
      serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
      serviceMonitorSelector:
        matchLabels:
          team: frontend
      ruleSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: alert-rules
          prometheus: rules
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: 400Mi
    scrape_interval: 15s  ##Error in this line.
```

I got this error message when compiling the config above:

`error: error validating "promethus.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(Prometheus): unknown field "scrape_interval" in com.coreos.monitoring.v1.Prometheus; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Thanks!

Comment: It is `scrapeInterval`, not `scrape_interval`

Answer (score 1):

`scrape_interval` is probably a parameter name in the prometheus config and not for the `Prometheus` object in k8s (which is read by prometheus-operator and used to generate actual config).

You can see in the [prometheus operator documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#prometheusspec) that the parameter you are looking for is `scrapeInterval`. Ensure correct indentation, this is supposed to be part of `spec:`.

Note that you do not have to change scrape interval globally. You can have per scrape target intervals defined in your ServiceMonitor objects.

Answer (score 0):

`scrape_interval` should go under the global [Prometheus configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/first_steps/#configuring-prometheus):

> Prometheus configuration is [YAML](https://yaml.org/start.html). The Prometheus download comes
> with a sample configuration in a file called `prometheus.yml` that is a
> good place to get started.

[Here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.19/config/testdata/conf.good.yml) is an example of a valid configuration YAML. Please notice:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 30s
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).
```

Your file named "promethus.yml" with `apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1` is not the same as the config file `prometheus.yml` I mentioned above and so, adding the `scrape_interval` to it would result in a validation error. **You cannot mix Prometheus configs with Prometheus Operator's ones.** These are different concepts.

I also recommend going through [the official guide](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/first_steps/) to get a better grip of the Prometheus and it's [configuration options](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/). Or stick with the [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator).